# How can I write a bashrc alias, that can call itself?

Tags: bash

I have following setup:

In my *~/.bashrc* I only call a script, where my actual settings are stored in:

```
source C:/path/To/mybashrc.sh
```

As you might see I use the git-bash for Windows (not sure, if that is important):

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Now I want to create a command, that makes me able to edit this script directly.
I found out how to get the directory of the script (1) and in another post I found out how to get the scripts name itself (2).

```
# Edit this file with nano
#(1)
__dir="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)"
#(2)
script_name=`basename "$0"`
# script_name="mybashrc.sh" # This works.
alias mybashrc='nano ${__dir}/${script_name}'
```

However my problem is that I can't combine these two solutions. When I try the script it opens a file called `bash` in the right directory in nano and not `mybashrc.sh`. The problem is probably the sourcing of the script in `.bashrc` and I wonder if I can still get to the desired solution. I am looking forward towards any hints.
(Of course the out-commented line works as the name is hard-coded, but that is not a solution for me as the script names differ in the real-world scenario, that I have.)

Comment: sooo `alias mybashrc='nano C:/path/To/mybashrc.sh'`?

Comment: @KamilCuk See last sentence.

Comment: Change `nano` with `echo` and tell us what you get when you do what you want.

Comment: `$0` will name an executable script, not one you have sourced. If the path is hardcoded in bashrc then get it from there. The better solution is to symlink `~/.bashrc` to the script you want to use, instead of a single line which sources it. Then you'll have a consistent reference.

Comment: @SEoF That path in where the script is located with the file called bash as I have described: `C:/path/To/bash`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path is already in `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}`. Your code takes directory from `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` and filename from `$0`. So don't take it from `$0`, take it from `BASH_SOURCE[0]`.

```
alias mybashrc="nano ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
```

However, BASH_SOURCE[0] may be relative. So let's make sure it's absolute.

```
alias mybashrc="nano $(readlink -f "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")"
```

will break on paths with spaces. A more experienced shell programmer may write:

```
alias mybashrc="nano $(printf "%q" "$(readlink -f "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")")"
```

Or you could use a variable that expands upon use, but still remember to quote the expansion:

```
thescript=$(readlink -f "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")
alias mybashrc='nano "$thescript"'
```

Comment: `bash: realink: command not found` Here a Windows problem occurs.

Comment: typo, it's `readlink`. Well, then replace `$0` with `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}`.

Comment: Oops yes. I haven't noticed. Now it works! Thanks a lot!